# Finding the Hash function of a Hash table

Tags: testing, computer-science

I took the foundation exam at UCF and there was this Hash Table question on it, that I am confused about. They seem to want you to figure out the hash function and determine what the other values "banana" could have been mapped to.

[image: A picture of the question.]

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be about quadratic probing and not finding a hash function that fits.  Quadratic probing says that if there is a collision then look for an "opening" in locations +1, +4, +9, +16 etc.  We start with assuming that the hash function returned 0 for "banana".  But we would either have banana in location 0, which we don't or in location +1 which is empty.  So we conclude that banana could never hash to location 0.  Next we look at location 1, which is empty, so again banana could not hash to location 1.  There are some hints in the possible points.  We find "no" until we try location 8.  Location 8 must have already been occupied, and similarly with location +1 (9).  When we look at location +4, we indeed find banana.  So the only Yes locations are 8, 9, 12.  Location 9 required probing all the way to +16.